# Admin menu vanishes

Tags: 7, navigation

I was installing some modules.  Suddenly, the helpful buttons across the top for admin mode disappeared.  Can anyone tell me what happened and what I have to do?

I am able to go to `{website}/admin` and essentially see the same buttons on the page that, I guess, I would see across the top of the page, but I wonder if I am missing out on some functionality.

But even if I still have the functionality, I still can not find the place where I can install new modules, and the system is telling me I need the "views" module to view some content I need to manage.

Answer (score 1):

You maybe disabled the `help module`

And to be able to install new modules through your admin you need to enable `Update manager`

Comment: Good tip.  This was one of the issues.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by ftp'ing some modules for the Admin Menu.  The modules I had already installed expected it and, when they did not find it, the menu could not be displayed.